# jQuery Ajax call to not expect any result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect

Im a little unfamiliar with `jQuery/ajax`.

Ive been using `$.post..` to send and receive message and it has greatly improved my site, however.

I need a facility to send an ajax cal to the server for validation

if validation is successful then I want the server to redirect
if not, it should comeback to the page and display the error message.

My question is which `jQuery` call is best suited for this.

From my experiece when I use `$.post('....')` and redirect on the server it for some reason will not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another ajax call within the ajax call or just trigger the form submission.

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("validate.php", $this.serialize()).done(function (valid) {
        if (valid) {
            $this.trigger("submit");
            //OR
            $.post("submit.php").done(function () { window.location = next; });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In your scenario, is the redirect being triggered in the jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are redirecting with PHP using header(), it will not redirect using ajax because content has already been sent to the client (you can only use this function before sanding any data)

You should try redirecting through javascript instead by using window.location.href="my new page"

you can find more information at the following links

http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

if you are not using PHP redirect, then I apologize

Answer (score 0):

You can use the underlying function of `$.post` which is `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'url',
                    data: 'json_or_string',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) {
                        if (json.clear == 1) {
                                            document.location.href = "redirect";
                        } else {
                        $('#errormessage').html('Error Validation');    
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (error) {

                    },


                });
```

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
$('#submitButtton').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        url: url/to/ajax-results.php',
        data: { $('form#my-form').serialize(); }
    }).done(function(data){
        if(data.response == 'error') {
            $('#results').html('<div class="error">'+data.report+'</div>');
            $('#results').show();
            return false;
        }

        window.location.href = data.redirect
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$errors = array();

$val1 = $_POST['val1'];
if(empty($val1)) {
    $errors[] = 'val1 cannot be empty';
}

if(count($errors) > 0) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'response' => 'error',
        'report' => 'send your errors array, or custom error message'
    ));
    exit();
} else {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'response' => 'ok',
        'redirect' => 'http://www.domain.com/url/to/redirect'
    ));
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: This answer to me is more clear, however can the redirect be done on the php side, rather than sending the redirect location to JS ?

Comment: short answer "No". Why JS redirection is not ok for you?